# Screen flicker on dual boot with 16.04 and 18.10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, login

I installed 18.10 today alongside 16.04. Ubuntu 18.10 works fine so far (apart from duplicity, but that's another story).

When I reboot back into 16.04, though, I see a Gnome screen that looks as though it's about to show login then the window manager drops out back to a full-screen black shell window with login prompt which is flickering so much that I can't login. Any ideas how to proceed?

Comment: are you using a NVIDIA graphics card? this sounds like a NVIDIA issue

Comment: No, Intel HD 4400 according to the manual